# Matrix operations in R: Populate new matrix from values from two matrices

Tags: r, csv, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices as different csvs, image below.
[image]

Matrix1) Series of elements on x, across stations in y

Matrix2) Series of charges on x, across elements on y

I want to create MATRIX 3 incorporating: Station as Y (column) Charges as X (rows) The charges are the multiplication of each element in the station*that particular charge and the addition of all the values. It makes more sense in the image. I can do it manually in Excel and it is tedious and time consuming to do across hundreds of observations and I need to changed the values across each row. I know there are methods to do this with R by converting my data frames to matrix (as.matrix) but all the examples i've seen specify all values in the matrix and the row/columns. This seems more tedious than excel with so many observations to list manually.

I am just not aware of other options and wanted to inquire if someone has experience with this sort of thing.

Thank you in advance.
I asked this question again for excel use just in case there may be a quicker solution with a less steep coding learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the inner product. The operator is `%*%`

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(
  .5,0,0,0,0,0,0,.25,0,0,.231,0,3,0,.25,0,0,.75,0,0,0,.5,0,0,1.5), 
  ncol=5)
mat2 <- matrix(c(1,3,2,0,0,2,1,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,4), ncol=3)
mat1 %*% mat2

#       [,1]  [,2] [,3]
# [1,] 0.962 1.462 0.00
# [2,] 0.000 0.000 2.00
# [3,] 6.750 7.000 0.25
# [4,] 0.000 0.000 0.00
# [5,] 0.500 0.500 6.00
```